# How to encode a URL as javascript string in PHP-generated HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Given this PHP code:

```
<a onclick="javascript:window.location.href='<?php echo $url;?>'"
```

What if there is a `'` in $url?

I tried using `json_encode($url)` but it won't be able to handle this.

Comment: Why do you use this `<a onclick="javascript:window.location.href=…"` anyways? Why not simply `<a href="…"`?

Comment: If the user doesn't have JS enabled and you don't set an href, it won't go anywhere FYI.

Comment: Because this is a contrived example.I am using it on div actually.

Comment: @Misier: have you tried the solution I posted?

Comment: It looks like hardcode,is there a more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_encode` will work. You just have to use it the right way:

```
<a onclick="javascript:window.location.href=<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($url)); ?>">
```

This will work since `json_encode` already returns an JavaScript expression with quotes. And `htmlspecialchars` is needed to escape possible HTML meta characters.

Comment: Er - what's the point of using location in the OP's context? Is this some sort of trick for storing the location in the browser's history when using ajax or some odd circumstance?

Comment: @meder: Don’t ask me, ask the OP.

Comment: No,it'll generate something like onclick="javascript:window.location.href="blablabla..""

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` will encode the inner double-quotes to `&quot;`, so it'll be fine. Also, can we lose the pointless ‘javascript:’ label?

Comment: Do you think href=&quot; is meaningful?

Comment: As bobince already said, the `htmlspecialchars` function will encode double quotes with `&quot;`. And `&quot;` inside a attribute value is legal and will be interpreted as a double quote character. So `title="&quot;foo&quot;"` will be evaluated to the attribute value `"foo"` (with double quotes).

Comment: @Gumbo,but location.href=&quot; is not legal at all!

Comment: @Gumbo: no, the problem is that `json_encode('abc')` returns `"abc"` (*including* the quote characters).  `htmlspecialchars` then encodes that as `&quot;abc&quot;`, but the problem is that he doesn't want the quotes there in the first place.

Comment: @Misier: The `&quot;` inside the attribute declaration is interpreted as `"`. Just like any other character reference is interpreted as the character it represents. “Some authors use the character entity reference "&quot;" to encode instances of the double quote mark (") since that character may be used to delimit attribute values.” (See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3) And the attribute declaration `"location.href=&quot;…&quot;"` is interpreted as `location.href="…"`.

Comment: @Gumbo aha, i was overthinking the problem

Comment: This is perfect answer. I'd like to see more people doing htmlspecialchars() on all values pushed to html and doing htmlspecialchars(json_encode()) on values pushed to javascript.

Comment: No,it's not,when it's faced with multibyte characters!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531881/how-to-make-jsconencode-work-with-multibyte-characters

Comment: @Misier: Only the event attributes beginning with `on…` are treated as JavaScript and will accept JSON data. But the `title` attribute value is not treated as JavaScript. So using `json_encode` is not right.