# How to make jscon_encode work with multibyte characters?

Tags: php, json, multibyte

```
echo '<a title=' .json_encode("按时间先后进行排序") . '>test</a>';
```

The above will generate something like "\u6309\u65f6\u95f4\u5148\u540e\u8fdb\u884c\u6392\u5e8f" and it's a mess!

Comment: Why not try json_decode and see if it outputs the desired string,

Comment: I'm using it to pass the string from php to html!

Comment: Why the heck would you want to do that? A browser can not do anything with JSON-encoded strings. Use `htmlentities()` if you’re worried about displaying.

Comment: Isn't jscon_encode the standard to pass string from php to html?

Comment: Like the answer in my another post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526940/how-to-encode-javascript-in-html-in-php

Answer (score 2):

No, that’s JSON. JSON encoders are free to copy characters as-is (except for doublequote, backslash, or control characters) or to encode them using the `\uxxxx` notation. So even while the above is not beautiful, it’s valid JSON and will ensure that the string will be decoded correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The `title` attribute value is not treated as JavaScript. Use `json_encode` only for converting a PHP type into a JavaScript/JSON expression.

Try this instead:

```
echo '<a title="按时间先后进行排序">test</a>';
```

But you would need to send your document with the the same encoding as your title text.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#74878

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `json_encode`, to encode your data, do it this way:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

This way you turn off string conversion that you do not want