# Passing a PHP var to a JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript

I went over many posts regarding this issue, yet can't figure out how to escape this syntax.

I'm simply trying to pop up an editing window via PHP `echo` of a JavaScript `window.open` and pass that window a prame from MySQL.

The code is `echo`'ed out along with a table that is dynamically generated via PHP. 
Inside that `echo` the last line is the problematic one, that I can't seem to get to function properly.

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open( "popup.php?message='.$Url.'", "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 350, width = 1022, resizable = 0 " )" class="bstyle">E</a></td>
```

Note: I have went over many posts here dealing with this issue, and tried out many solutions, none of which worked out. I'm sure this is very simple to handle, yet I have been steering at this thing it is slipping my attention.

Comment: post all of the code, right now I'm guessing `<?php echo $Url; ?>` will fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode a URL as javascript string in PHP-generated HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526940/)

Answer (score 1):

You can embed PHP into your HTML:

```
<a href="#"
   onClick="window.open(
      'popup.php?message=<?php echo $Url; ?>',
      'myWindow', 
      'status = 1, height = 350, width = 1022, resizable = 0'
   )"
   class="bstyle">
      E
</a>
```

**P.S.** The weird indentation is just so that you can read it here on SO. Don't actually use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="#" onClick="window.open(\'popup.php?message='.$Url.'\', \'myWindow\', 
  \'status = 1, height = 350, width = 1022, resizable = 0\')" class="bstyle">E</a></td>';
```

If you were writing html, and wrote this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open( "popup.php?message=blah", "myWindow", 
  "status = 1, height = 350, width = 1022, resizable = 0 " )" class="bstyle">E</a></td>
```

your `onclick` wouldn't work because it would just hold the value `window.open(`. You can define the string within the string value of `onclick` using single quotes. And since in my case I (not sure if you are, but it looks like it) am defining my string to echo using single quotes, I need to escape the ones in my string with the `\` character.

Answer (score 0):

Use a backslash to escape characters in PHP.

```
echo '<a href="#" onClick="window.open( \'popup.php?message='.$Url.'\', \'myWindow\', \'status = 1, height = 350, width = 1022, resizable = 0\' );" class="bstyle">E</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a variable inside your HTML code by echo'ing the variable.

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open ( 'popup.php?message=<?php echo $Url; ?>', 'myWindow', 'status = 1, height = 350, width = 1022, resizable = 0 ' )" class="bstyle">E</a></td>
```

I would also like to recommend [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) in this case. 
The reason behind this is, because you echo out the $Url variable. 
Whenever $Url contains HTML characters like for example " or ' then your javascript call will break.

In your popup.php you can then [urldecode](http://php.net/urldecode) the message so that it becomes normal again.